# ROS Gazebo block laser plugin and MultiRayShape in 1.6.16

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I've been developing a simulation using simulator_gazebo version 1.6.10 succesfully. I've recently upgraded to 1.6.16 and am having issues with the block laser functionality. It appears majority of the point cloud seems to be going through the ground plane as well as basic spawned objects (such as a box). As a result , the range returned for majority of the rays is returned as max range. It seems more of an issue with the individual rays used in MultiRayshapes. Any ideas? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/102/ros-gazebo-block-laser-plugin-and-multirayshape-in-1.6.16/) by [Dubya](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/13/dubya/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) on 2013-05-06**:
Were you able to resolve the problem? I am trying to get the ros block laser plugin to work in standalone gazebo and having problems.

**Comment by [gazer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/344/gazer/) on 2013-07-02**:
peshala, did you solve your problem? I am also trying to get ros block laser plugin to work for my swissranger_camera; it is weird that block laser is the plugin to use in Camera; however, I desperate to publish the poitlcound sensor message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Sounds like a bug.  If you'd like, [file a ticket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues).

Unfortunately, it's hard to find time to fix problems in older versions of Gazebo (you're running Gazebo 1.0.x from within the ROS simulator_gazebo 1.6.x release, and we're now on Gazebo 1.3.x).  If a patch to fix the problem is provided, we'll make an updated release.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0